# How to debug c code remotely

Tags: c, debugging

I have a server which is running c code and another server where my development environment is present. Can I use something like remote debugging to debug C code on my development server.

I am using unix development and deployment environment.

Comment: I'd say code should be debugged _before_ it gets deployed to a remote server.

Comment: @Elias: Maybe you have not the full environment for the prog itself. Maybe you need data base content, storage, high performance hardware or whatsoever. So it is a standard use case to edit/compile/link on a dedicated build machine and run and debug on the target host. For embedded this is the standard. But OP don't answer the question which environment he is working on.

Answer (score 2):

We all have no idea which environment you use! Win/Linux/Mac/...

On linux:
run gdb with

```
target remote <ip-number>:<port>
```

and on the target system:

```
gdbserver <prog-to-debug>
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be, just use [*ssh*](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1) to connect to your server, and run a debug session on there (e.g. `gdb`). The only thing you have to bear in mind is that if you want useful debug output, you probably want to compile leaving [debug symbols](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3.6/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) in, before you deploy (but that is a consideration no matter where you're debugging).

Comment: If you use a ssh session and debug on the remote server, you have no access to the source code of the prog itself which makes this method not really helpful I think. If you want to get access to the source you have to mount the source directory remote from the remote server. Looks a bit complicated to me :-)

Comment: Well the assumption would be that you are sshing in from the development server on which you have your source files. In any case however, your solution is the better one. Infact, I upvoted it myself ;)